# Use option value as a filename variable in a jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

how can I pass the option value to the filename below? My purpose is to create files e.g. 1.php 2.php 3.php .... but I dont know how to pass it as a variable.
Thanks.

```
    <form>
        <select id="termid">
            <option value="">- select -</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>  
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
$('#termid').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#some_div_below_select').load(val + '.php',
    {
        value: val
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#termid option:selected').val()` instead of `THE OPTION VALUE` should work.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4t8T/) to demonstrate getting the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the selected `option` when you handle the `change` event, and you can then use that to build up the string for your URL, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#termid').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $('#some_div_below_select').load(selectedVal  + '.php', { "value" : selectedVal });
  });
});
```